# Weak and strong convergence in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

$H$ is a Hilbert space and $T$ is a linear operator from $H$ to itself. If $x_n$ converges weakly to $0$ and $Tx_n$ converges strongly to $0$, then we have $(Tx_n,x_n)$ converges to $0$.

What about the converse? Namely, if $x_n$ converges weakly to $0$ and $(Tx_n,x_n)$ converges to $0$, do we have $Tx_n$ converges strongly to $0$?

Comment: $(Tx_n,x_n)$ is a number. I guess you mean "converges to zero" when you say "converges strongly to zero"

Comment: Yes. I will fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample for the question you raise in the comment to another answer:

Consider $H = \ell^2$ and define $T$ via
$$
Tx = (x_2, -x_1, x_4, -x_3, \ldots).
$$
By construction, $(Tx,x) = 0$ for all $x \in \ell^2$.

Hence, for every sequence $(x_n)\subset H$ with $x_n \rightharpoonup 0$ you have $(Tx_n,x_n) = 0 \to 0$.

However, $T$ is an isometry, hence $x_n \not\to 0$ implies $Tx_n \not\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Counterexample: Let $H = \ell_2$ and $T$ be the right shift operator: $T(e_n ) = e_{n+1}$. Let $x_n = e_n$.

Then $\{e_n\}$ converges weakly to $0$, $\langle Te_n, e_{n}\rangle = 0$. But $\{Te_n\}$ does not converge strongly to $0$.

Comment: That's good. But I'm sorry since I realize that I missed something. What I really mean is: for every sequence $x_n$ converging to $0$, one has $(Tx_n,x_n)$ converges to $0$, do we have $Tx_n$ converges strongly to $0$?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What is your $x_n$ in $Tx_n$ in the last sentence? @tingting